# Android reveive sms

Tags: android

I'm trying to get SMS message in an android application, however my code is not working. The Toast is not showing the result when I received a message. What could be the problem in my following code?

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MySms extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = 
"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

public MySms() {
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            // get sms objects
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            if (pdus.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            // large message might be broken into many
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) 
        pdus[i]);
                sb.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
            }
            String sender = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
            String message = sb.toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, message, 
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, sender, 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
      }
    }
   }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.user.sms" >
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
                />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MySms"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action 
  android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Why you are exporting the broadcast

Comment: Put a log in on receive

Answer (score 0):

```
//Manifest File should be like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.smsexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.smsexample.MySms">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>


//MySms Class Code

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context; 
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;



    public class MySms extends BroadcastReceiver

    {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get Bundle object contained in the SMS intent passed in
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] smsm = null;
        String sms_str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            // Get the SMS message
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            smsm = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < smsm.length; i++) {
                smsm[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                sms_str += "Sent From: " + smsm[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                sms_str += smsm[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                sms_str += "\r\n";
                Log.v("Message Body:",sms_str);
                Toast.makeText(context, sms_str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will not work for marshmallow or Android N because for that you need to give permission on run time